# ColdFusion - cfproc param : How do I call stored proc with db defined variable %TYPE?

Tags: oracle, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfqueryparam, cfstoredproc

I have a stored proc in Oracle. One of the input params is a defined type (see below). The error I get whenever I call the cfstoredproc is "expression is of wrong type ORA-06550". It's a formatted varchar, it's a table column. There's no CFPROCPARAM type that matches that.

The type is a package-defined specific format (table column): EMAIL_ADDRESSES_TABLE.USER_ID%TYPE. 
The table column USER_ID is: USER_ID VARCHAR2(8 BYTE)

The USER_ID is a 0-padded numeric, like '00001234'

my call:

```
<cfstoredproc procedure="PK_EMAIL.get_emails" datasource="#MYDSN#">
  <cfprocparam type="in" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" variable="p_user_id" value="#formattedUserId#">
  <cfprocparam type="in" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_NUMERIC" variable="p_active_only" value="1">
  <cfprocresult name="spResult">
</cfstoredproc>
```

the stored proc function:

```
FUNCTION get_emails(
  p_user_id        IN EMAIL_ADDRESSES_TABLE.USER_ID%TYPE,
  p_active_only    IN SIMPLE_INTEGER
) RETURN EMAIL_ADDRESSES_TABLE;
```

The error I get from the system is:

```
[Macromedia][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]ORA-06550: line 1, column 18: PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Comment: Please show the part of the stored proc that declares the input paramters.

Comment: I thought I had posted everything, but here's the relevant table declaration: TABLE EMAIL_ADDRESSES_TABLE ... USER_ID VARCHAR2(8 BYTE) NOT NULL

Comment: Not sure about oracle, but with other databases, stored procedures and functions are different things.  That being the case, my interpretation of the term, "stored proc function" was that your stored procedure called a function.  Was that not correct?

Comment: @DanBracuk - oh, aha. I've called lots of storedprocs in the past. But you're right, this is a public function, not a "procedure". Now I have to figure out how I can call that.

Comment: I would assume you call it like any other function - `get_emails( userId, true)`

Answer (score 1):

@DanBracuk helped me figure this out.

These functions were originally set up to be exposed as Java API calls.

Short answer: It's a "FUNCTION", not a "PROCEDURE". ColdFusion cannot call a DB Function directly.

The work-around (info provided by someone here who did this once): Need to create an Oracle PROCEDURE that calls the function. It just acts as intermediary between CF and the Oracle function.

Comment: I think that if you can call the function from a query statement (like from whatever the Oracle equivalent of SQL server Management Studio), you should be able to call it from within a <cfquery> tag.

Comment: @Carl is correct. `SELECT myFunction() AS function_result FROM DUAL` is a valid query from ColdFusion (assuming the output is right).